# Issue faced while uploading file using JMeter (Getting error - Import could not start - Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Tags: file-upload, jmeter

I'm facing issue while uploading a file through JMeter. When file was uploaded manually, it was successful. The file is CSV file and it's contents are: Mr.,Perf,Driver4,LIC1,10003,12/31/2025,12/31/2025,CA,USA

**Request Captured in fiddler:**

```
POST https://WebSiteName/MainPage/Drivers/UploadDrivers HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: https://WebSiteName/MainPage/Drivers/Main
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7e21cd231003b8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: WebSiteName
Content-Length: 691
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: intercom-lou-zjtmncjn=1; __utma=1.1400002961.1527162610.1533116464.1533118526.10; __utmz=1.1527162610.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); MainPageusername=akalambe; MainPagerememberchkbox=true; __utmv=1.|1=FleetId=67468d0b-4f3d-4693-9d06-ed226d27198c=1^2=UserId=f0467301-c934-4354-87a1-d875f56359de=1^3=RegionName=FW02=1; __utmt=1; __utmb=1.2.10.1533118526; AWSELB=6703C92B1A36D2911BDDEF67F947B6D8FA09E46F7AB993BF5EEE818483244FFE1C5B9ED7D743F6F7966ACAFFC21671252299970FE39D531FCECB082F45AABB8B505FB5E6AA; __utmc=1; DirectorAuth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ainPageUserPreferredLocale=en-US; DirectorSession=oceg01jzjoqjq5iybq4mg3im


-----------------------------7e21cd231003b8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="EntityImportTemplate.csv"
Content-Type: text/plain

Title,FirstName,LastName,LicenceClass,LicenceNo,ExpirationDate,LastPhysical,LicenceState(Abbreviated),"LicenceCountry(Abbreviations include: USA,CAN,MEX,AUS,NZ)"
Mr.,Perf,Driver4,LIC1,10003,12/31/2025,12/31/2025,CA,USA
-----------------------------7e21cd231003b8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"

EntityImportTemplate.csv
-----------------------------7e21cd231003b8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="OwnerId"

67468d0b-4f3d-4693-9d06-ed226d27198c
-----------------------------7e21cd231003b8—
```

**Response Captured in fiddler:**

{"Success":true,"ImportMessages":[{"ErrorDescription":"Driver verified","Tag":null,"TimeStampUtc":"/Date(1533123584180)/","MessageType":0,"Text":"Driver verified"}]}

**But response in JMeter for same file upload is:**

{"Success":false,"ImportMessages":[{"ErrorDescription":"Import could not start - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","Tag":null,"TimeStampUtc":"/Date(1533717886829)/","MessageType":2,"Text":"Import could not start"}]}

- [JMeter HTTP Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBZyO.jpg)
- [HTTP Header Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ6WO.jpg)
- [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKODn.jpg)
- [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPymH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The way of building your upload request is quite flaky, I would rather recommend using `Files Upload` tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and specify your CSV file there like:

[image: JMeter File Upload]

Also don't forget to tick `Use multipart/form-data for POST` box

---

In general the best way to build a file upload request with JMeter is just recording it with [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Copy your `EntityImportTemplate.csv` file to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Start HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
3. Configure your browser to use JMeter as the proxy
4. Issue your upload request
5. The relevant HTTP Request sampler should be created under the [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)

Comment: Not sure why but Recording controller does not capture file upload method. Same is the case with Blazemeter.

Comment: When I use files upload, I am getting response - {"Success":false,"ImportMessages":[{"ErrorDescription":"No file chosen","Tag":null,"TimeStampUtc":"\/Date(1533722105695)\/","MessageType":0,"Text":"No file chosen"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Advanced Tab and select "Java" as implementation.I hope it will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends on how web application under test responds to Jmeter scripts.

For me, once I was trying to upload docx through Jmeter and it was uploaded to file share location but thrown an error - "File format is not supported" even with correct uploading API configurations as recommended.

File Path: filename.docx, Parameter name: class name of UI element used to upload document e.g. button to browse file from disk MIME TYPE: vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document Select 'Use multipart/form-data' It worked successfully without any error and un-corrupted document content with below configuration some how:

File Path: filename.docx, Parameter name: Blank (Yes.. do not provide any value in here for Parameter column just leave it blank) MIME TYPE: vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document Deslect 'Use multipart/form-data'